# Small Image Size by new Instagram API graph.instagram.com/me/media

Tags: api, widget, instagram, display

I want to make a widget to display Instagram feed. Through graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=caption,media_type,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url&access_token=XXXXX I get the images. But in the widget I need a size of 150x150px.

oembed cannot be used, Limitations: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/embedding#limitations

Well, in a div size of 150x150px, an image of 800x1200 is also not needed.

How can I get other sizes?

Answer (score 4):

The latest Instagram API doesn't have any ability to fetch an alternative size image on their basic display. It is possible to fetch a thumbnail URL using the oembed api, but this seems dev overkill.
The Instagram Basic Display API seems to be evolving, so this may be updated in the future.
For now, it seems that your only option is to always fetch the original sized images.

Comment: You could also cache the images = process them with an image pre processor like PHP GD and render a smaller cropped/resized image at 150px. You would have an initial server delay for processing the images, but once cached it wouldnt be a problem.